# How to resize draft js editor uploaded images

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I was working with draft js editor but cannot able to resize the selected image while rendering on the editor.
Just want to fix selected image width that greater to blog width to blog width.

Below is my code which i have done so far but not getting how to control the size of the image

```
    pickMedia = (event) => {
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
        var file = event.target.files[0];
        this.getBase64(file, (result) => {
            const newEditorState = this.insertImage(this.state.editorState, result);
            this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState });
        });
        // const newEditorState = this.insertImage(this.state.editorState, base64);
        // this.setState({ editorState: newEditorState });
    }
    focus = () => {
        this.editor.focus();
    };

    insertImage = (editorState, base64) => {
        const contentState = editorState.getCurrentContent();
        const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
            'image',
            'IMMUTABLE',
            { src: base64 },
        );
        const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
        const newEditorState = EditorState.set(
            editorState,
            { currentContent: contentStateWithEntity },
        );
        return AtomicBlockUtils.insertAtomicBlock(newEditorState, entityKey, ' ');
    };

    getBase64(file, cb) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        reader.onload = function () {
            cb(reader.result)
        };
        reader.onerror = function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ', error);
        };
    }

                <div className="editor-container-box neuehaasunica" onClick={this.focus} >
                    <Editor
                        editorState={this.state.editorState}
                        onChange={this.onChange}
                        plugins={plugins}
                        placeholder="Enter your thoughts"
                        ref={(element) => {
                            this.editor = element;
                        }}
                    />
                    <input id="media-image-upload"
                        accept="image/* video/*"
                        type="file"
                        ref="mediaUpload"
                        style={{ display: 'none' }}
                        onChange={(event, type) => this.pickMedia(event)}
                    />
                    <div className='flex-end'>
                        <div className="media-icon-container" onClick={() => { this.refs.mediaUpload.click() }}>
                            <i class="fal fa-photo-video" ></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="media-post-btn neuehaasunica">POST</div>
            </div>
```

Comment: hi and welcome to StackOverflow!

please [edit] your question to clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. see the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.